# Python creating money in a grid

Tags: python, grid, currency

I created a piece of code where a player can move around in search of treasure. When a player lands on a treasure, 10 coins are added whilst if a player lands on a goblin, all coins are deducted. I have created a function for this "money", although it does not seem to work. Whenever I run the code it seems as if nothing from the money function works. Could anyone please edit my code so that it works, or offer any advice, thanks. Here is my code:

```
import time
from random import *
# Set up Initial Variables
Money = 0
grid = []
character = "X" 
# player_loc will hold the x, y location of the player
player_loc = (0, 0)
# These are a mapping of direction
NORTH = "N"
SOUTH = "S"
 EAST  = "E"
WEST  = "W"   #All variables used for Later on
Treasure = "T"
Goblin = "G"


def menu(): #functiom
   c = input(" To quit this program, type 'quit'    To start the game, type 'start'")#Users choice to start game
   if c == "quit": 
         exit()
   elif c == "start": #If users input is to start the game the all of this appears
      print("Welcome to the treasure hunt game!")
      time.sleep(1)
      print(" ")
      print("These are the rules! You have a choice of a grid ranging from a 3x3 choice to a 20x20 choice")
      print(" ")
      time.sleep(2)
      print("in these grids, bandits and treasure chests will spawn at random locations, hidden to you.")
      print(" ")
      time.sleep(3)
      print("You will have a choice of the amount of goblins and treasures you would like to spawn in, ranging from 1-20.")
      print(" ")
      time.sleep(3)
      print("You will move around the map, in search of treasures which will give you 10 gold. Although landing on a goblin would deduct the amount of gold to 0.")
      print(" ")
      time.sleep(3)
      print("Furthurmore, just deciding on a position you would like to move to, would give you an extra 1 piece of gold.")
      print(" ")
      time.sleep(3)
      print("You can only find the same treasure chest two times before it's replaced by a bandit.")
      print(" ")
      time.sleep(3)
      print("To check the amount of gold you have and the amount of bandits and treasure chests in the grid. Simply type 'status'")
      print(" ")
      time.sleep(3)
      print("Don't forget! If you have collected all the treasure chests and you don't have 100 gold, you lose the game!")
      print(" ")
      time.sleep(3)
      print("Good luck, you will now be entered into the game")
      print(" ")
      time.sleep(2)
      x = input("What is your name?")
      username = x
      time.sleep(2)
      print ("Hello,", username,"! Let's jump into the game!")
      setupGrid()
      Chests_and_Goblins() 


def setupGrid(): #New function for creating grid
    global grid #Adding/creating global variables
    global row
    global N
    N = input("How big would you like the grid to be?") #User input
    time.sleep(2)
    while int(N) > 20 : #Changing N to an integer so computer understamds
          N =input("That number is too high or too low, The grid has to be at a size of under 20x20. Or 3x3 and larger. Please try again")
   else:
       while int(N) < 3 : # Asking the user to input again as number is too high or low
          N = input("That number is too low, the grid has to be a size of over 3x3. Please try again")
       for x in range(0, (int(N))):#For everything in range N
            row = [] #The N amount of rows are created
            for y in range(0, (int(N))): #For everything in range N
               if x == player_loc[0] and y == player_loc[1]: #If the positions is equal to th player location
                    row.append(character) # Add the character in
                else:
                  row.append('O') #Add the same amount of 0's as N
           grid.append(row) 


 def Chests_and_Goblins():
   global z
   global grid
   global row
   global N
   global Treasure
   print("How many chests would you like in the grid?")     
   time.sleep(2)
   B = input("The amount of chests you like is given by the amount of C's")
   print("How many Bandits would you like in the grid?")     
   time.sleep(2)
   F = input("The amount of Bandits you like is given by the amount of B's")
   for each in B:
      grid[randint(0, int(N)-1)][randint(0, int(N)-1)] = Treasure
   for each in F:
      grid[randint(0, int(N)-1)][randint(0, int(N)-1)] = Goblin





def moveSouth(n):
    global player_loc
    grid[player_loc[0]][player_loc[1]] = "O"
    grid[player_loc[0] + n][player_loc[1]] = character
    player_loc = (player_loc[0] + n, player_loc[1])
    money()

def moveNorth(n):
    global player_loc
    grid[player_loc[0]][player_loc[1]] = "O"
    grid[player_loc[0] - n][player_loc[1]] = character
    player_loc = (player_loc[0] - n, player_loc[1])
    money()

def moveEast(n):
    global player_loc
    grid[player_loc[0]][player_loc[1]] = "O"
    grid[player_loc[0]][player_loc[1] + n] = character
    player_loc = (player_loc[0], player_loc[1] + n)
    money()

def moveWest(n):
    global player_loc
    grid[player_loc[0]][player_loc[1]] = "O"
    grid[player_loc[0]][player_loc[1] - n] = character
    player_loc = (player_loc[0], player_loc[1] - n)
    money()

def gridRunner():
    while True:
        for row in grid:
            print (row)

         switch = {NORTH : moveNorth,
                  SOUTH : moveSouth,
                  EAST  : moveEast,
                  WEST  : moveWest }
        print (" ")
        time.sleep(2)
        P = input("What direction would you like to move in? North (N), South(S), East(E) or West(W)?").upper()

        if P not in switch:
            print ("invalid move")
            continue

        distance = int(input("How far would you like to move in this direction? (blocks are the units)"))
        switch[P](distance)

def money():
   global player_loc
   global character
   global Treasure
   if player_loc == Treasure:
      print("Well done, You have gained coins")
   else:
      print ("You got nothing")





menu()
gridRunner()
```

Comment: For now, I only made it so that if the player lands on treasure. Nothing to do with Goblins yet.

Comment: I recommend you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and give a failing test of the money function.

Comment: Just some thoughts: global should only be used if you are going to modify said variable inside your function. Your Treasures loop, is it expecting 'TTT' as input for 3 treasures, it actually counts the number of characters at the moment, same for Goblin. A better Grid printer would be: print '\n'.join([' '.join(x for x in grid[y]) for y in xrange(len(grid))]). You should check that the cell is empty before assigning Treasures and Goblins. Also check if a movement gets out of the grid, as you don't check it at the moment

Comment: Oh and the money function is not working because when you call it the grid has been changed and it now has value character.

Comment: @Aquiles Thanks, but could you please edit the code for me? I am struggling so much. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your money function doesn't even store/manipulate the money variable >.>

It simply prints an output based on an 'if' condition. Shouldn't it be like:

```
if player_loc == Treasure:
      print("Well done, You have gained coins")
      Money += 10
else:
      print ("You got nothing")
      Money = 0
```

Comment: Ah, I just tried that and it seems as if there is no difference. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a working code but it's better for this kind of stuff to do it yourself so I'm just going to place some functions here that can point you in the right direction:

```
def money(x, y):
    global MONEY
    if GRID[x][y] == TREASURE: MONEY += 10; print 'You found a treasure'
    elif GRID[x][y] == GOBLIN: MONEY = 0; print 'You lost your money'
```

This money function will check given a position in the grid if it's something that should be done with the money, as you can see we use a global because we are going to modify the value of the global value, the reason why we pass the x,y and not use our position will be apparent on the next function:

```
def move_west():
    global GRID, POSITION
    x, y = POSITION[0], POSITION[1]
    if y != 0:
        money(x, y-1)
        GRID[x][y], GRID[x][y-1] = EMPTY, AVATAR
        POSITION = (x, y-1)
    else: print 'You\'ve hit a wall'
```

As you can see in this function, first of all we get the current position from a global value that in my case is a tuple (x,y). We check that the way we are moving is valid, and then we call the money function with our future position before changing it, the reason why we do this is because right now the value can be either EMPTY, TREASURE or GOBLIN, but after we move will definitely be AVATAR so we would have changed it and our money function would never see if there was something to do there. After we call the money function, we update both the grid and the position of our character in the global variables. Hopefully this will help you.